# Expressjs Adding :id param to url broke static content

Tags: node.js, express

I return **same view for both** /new and edit/:id

however when it is rendered **styles and js files are not found for 
edit/:id**

Why is this happening for Expressjs. It is supposed to always be relative to public folder, isn't it?

Routes:

```
router.get('/new', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'New', id: 0 });
});

router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Edit', id: req.params.id });
});
```

On the view i have my styles like this

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

All content is inside public folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need absolute urls for your scripts and links (start with a slash).

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Your browser sees a relative path, so it is requesting the content at

`edit/javascript/jquery-3.1.0.min.js` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Wonderful - Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will but stack-overflow asked me to wait 10 min before accepting answer